# User resource file inside repeater error

Tags: asp.net, html, resources, repeater

I'm using a resource file inside a header template in a repeater and it's giving me an error when I write `runat="server"` on the table. I get the error:

> Unexpected end of file looking for close HeaderTemplate tag

When I dont write `runat="server"` it gives me also the error:

> Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources:Weather,styletable1 %>' are not allowed. Use " /> instead

The code:

```
<asp:repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style='<%$ Resources:file1,styletable1 %>' >
            <tr>
                <td>........</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?